# Call history for windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am developing a application which may access to call history in windows phone 8.i need to know how to add a call history in that app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to access call history details on Windows Phone.
There is no public API for this data so you will not be able to build such an application.

Comment: but i developing VoIP application we make call in our dialer only not through windows dialer using that we can get call history detail

Comment: @pradeep - if you are maintaining your own call history for a VoIP type app, you can access that since it is your apps own data.  This would typically be a collection of objects that represent the details of the call, and can be saved to a data store for access at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Phone.dll, and the included functions like
`PhoneOpenCallLog(...)` and `PhoneGetCallLogEntry(...)` with simple interop you're be able to access the windows call history.

Edit: These are available in Windows Mobile, but not in Windows Phone. You can vote for Microsoft to add this feature here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/4386451-api-to-read-phone-call-history