# Windows phone 8 - Application getting event fired from incoming call

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

After looking at those links:

- [control-information-on-call-windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632964/control-information-on-call-windows-phone-8)
- [call-history-for-windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567501/call-history-for-windows-phone-8)

it seems that there is no way to do drop a call or to get calls history from an application using Windows Phone.

I would need to get a notification when an incoming call is starting/ending on Windows Phone 8.

- Is is possible to do that even if I am not an OEM? If yes, what is the API to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons microsoft do not want to allow the apps to get incomming calls info, call history or message data. so a straight no on that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

**Reason**: Security and Privacy of customer.